# How can i import html with php?

Tags: php

This is a really simple one but it's driving me crazy.

I want to import regular HTML code with the help of PHP.

```
<?php get_thefile ?>
```

Is that correct? And what shall the `thefile.php` contain to get it right except my HTML content that I want to import of course!

More information

In a category part of a website i want to put a sidebar that will show some information, this can be anything from html to flash. This content will change time to time so insteed of editing 100 pages i want to just edit this file, My php skill is 0,1% and i can't relly find what i shall exactly do, So what i need is

1: The code to place in the page

2: What i shall put in the file before ? and after ? my content that i want to import

The file will be in the same folder on server as the main page, the page is php and it's wordpress

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if it's external HTML, you could use

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://EXTERNAL_URL'); ?>
```

again, not fully sure what you're trying to do.  i hope this helps.

Comment: you could just use the include example like so `<? include 'thefile.php'; ?>` this will modularize some content when needed to be included, no pun inteded :)

Comment: Am just getting this all the time Warning: file_get_contents(/../netent.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/footer.php on line 21

My code is  <?php file_get_contents("netent.txt"); ?>

have tryed with html and php to, The hole url can't be necessary

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to directly output the file, use [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: +1 because it avoids the need for PHP to consider parsing the file (include/require) and it's only one function (If you want to get technical, `echo file_get_contents()` is a language construct and one function, but that's not the point).

Comment: @Richard: The type of the file is totally irrelevant. What is important, is that it's executed as a PHP script. Check your webserver's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly want to use `include` as described [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use `$html = file_get_contents('link_to_html.html');`

Comment: add an `echo $html;` to this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include 'thefile.php'; ?>
```

[`include` Documentation](http://php.net/include)