# Using PHP to include HTML with CSS stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, less

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198408/406110

`login.php` file: **(despite being a php file, it doesn't have php code, only html)**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="/js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link 
        href="login.less" 
        rel="stylesheet/less" 
        type="text/css">
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

`load.php` file:

```
<?php print file_get_contents('login.php'); ?>
```

I would like to load the content of the file `login.php` using `load.php`. It is possible, HTML is being write correctly, but CSS/LESS is not loading:

`login.less` file:

```
body { background-color: red; }
```

Why?

**Edit 1**

> I am using *"Client-side Usage"* to run LESS files.

Seems it is a **LESS** problem. But why isn't it working?

Problem solved:

Somehow, LESS was not being compiled, I changed from Client-side Usage to a compiling approach. Thank you everybody!

Comment: you sure you just want the contents of login.php? if you want it to execute as php you should probably `include('login.php')`.

Comment: @Octopus just content (:

Comment: I think this is less of a PHP issue and more of a browser rendering issue.  Have you done any debugging in your browser to check for errors?

Comment: Do you have any `404` message in your console? What if you use `<link href="/login.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">` (note the slash) in your login file?

Comment: you're supposed to compile less code. you can't just have a browser load it directly. i see that it only has css, so I am questioning your choice of file extensions in two cases now.

Comment: are all php files inside the same folder? use error reporting

Comment: LESS is not working, why?

Comment: The browser only understands `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css"/>` if you point to a non-css file it won't work.  You need to generate the CSS file from your LESS file(s).

Comment: Less stylesheet `<link>`s should go *before* `less.js` script.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want is just an include:

```
<?php include('login.php'); ?>
```

This just includes the contents of the other file (in this case login.php) into your current file.

Comment: `include` behaves in the same way, also not working, stylesheet file (css/less) not being applied.

Comment: `(despite being a php file, it doesn't have php code, only html)`.  So it's not really going to make a difference which is why I deleted my answer that had this.

Comment: @Devon is it related to the LESS note in the OP's question? If so, that just needs to be a build step to generate the final CSS.

Comment: @Richard I think the piece you are missing is related to LESS.  Your LESS file is an intermediate file that is used to generate the final CSS output. Remember that the browser only speaks HTML/JavaScript/CSS... any other languages/formats you want to use must be "built" to generate the final outputs.

Comment: @scunliffe seems you are right, but how can I fix it?

Comment: You can compile the CSS at the command line - documentation here: http://lesscss.org/#command-line-with-rhino

Comment: I was using Client-side way, not compiled. It runs just in the local network, no worries with huge traffic.

Comment: Ah, yeah they have a local dev version (I haven't used it). Since the final production output version **should** be compiled, I tend to use the generated output.

Comment: I'll try to use an "compiled" way to get final output from LESS. If you want, change your answer to include LESS approach and I will mark it as correct. @scunliffe